# Using monorepo with Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, monorepo

I am trying to move few of my Symfony projects into one monorepo. This is my structure.

```
packages/
├─ symfony-project-1/
│  ├─ public/
│  │  ├─ index.php
│  ├─ composer.json
├─ symfony-project-2/
│  ├─ public/
│  │  ├─ index.php
│  ├─ composer.json
vendor/
composer.json
```

I use package `symplify/monorepo-builder` to merge all of my project's `composer.json` file into the root one. Then I split my packages to READ-ONLY repositories.

To production, I would like to deploy the READ-ONLY repository. So for example, only the content of the directory `symfony-project-1` would be transferred to the production server and the `vendor` folder would be installed directly to the same directory. Here comes the problem.

How can I make the front-controller `index.php` load `./../../../vendor` in development and `./../vendor` in production?

The `index.php` looks normally like this:

```php
<?php
// public/index.php
use App\Kernel;

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';

return function (array $context) {
    return new Kernel($context['APP_ENV'], (bool) $context['APP_DEBUG']);
};
```

I tried this:

```php
...

if (is_file(dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php')) {
    $autoloadPath = dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';
} else {
    $autoloadPath = dirname(__DIR__).'/../../vendor/autoload_runtime.php';
}

require_once $autoloadPath;

...
```

But then Symfony tries to read `.env` file from the root of the monorepo not the project root (I get this: `Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read the "/Users/xxx/work/monorepo/.env" environment file.`).

How to solve this in monorepo?

Comment: Are these projects in any way connected? If not: is there any good reason to move them to a single repo?

Comment: Yes, they are all projects for one website (main page, subdomains, landing pages, ...). They communicate with each other and they are business related. So when something needs to be changed at one of the websites, most probably it has to be changed on all of them. That's why I would like to implement monorepo.

Comment: Have you thought about **properly** integrating them into one project?

Comment: All of the main parts were actually one project for several years (only the landing pages were always separated), but because of different business needs for each part we separated them. It's preparation for us, because we are slowly introducing API in the core and want to replace some other parts with javascript SPA in mid-term future. That's why we see monorepo as a good way for now.

Comment: I resolved my problems with docker on the local machine :) Add vendor as separate volumes, but didn't need .env file. Also, you could search in `symfony/dotenv` for `CONST` that could be overwritten and change the path for load `.env`. Also you could have in the main folder merged all `.env` files in one - I don't see problem with that.